# How did windows application "phone link" open the webpage automaticly can IT also open the files on our computer

Tags: android, html, windows, windows-phone-8

using your phone to single click the link and send to the computer,it can open the browser and the webpage including the webpage cache like video Progress bar;
i wonder why can it open the browser from the link ,and can it can also  open the browser with single link, can we open files also using it

with single link to our phone we can open the link we can open file from computer ,we can

. using our phone to open some aplications
. link multiple phone and control it together
. write a webpage for control computer using phone with single link when we need

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.